# Android: Setting View height to 0

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a RelativeLayout that includes three elements:  a TableLayout at the top that contains some controls (layout_alignParentTop = true), a LinearLayout at the bottom (layout_alignParentBottom = true) that contains a couple buttons and a ListView that stretches between them (using layout_below and layout_above the two elements).  That works great, but under certain circumstances, the bottom LinearLayout needs to go away.  If I use setVisibility to set it to View.GONE or set its height to 0 using setLayoutParams(), the ListView is stubbornly refusing to resize to take up the newly freed space.  I've tried calling requestLayout() on basically everything in the hierarchy, and nothing seems to work.  If I fire up the hierarchy viewer, I can see that the view is gone/has layout_height of 0, but it still doesn't work.

Ironically, after the hierarchy viewer is done, the layout corrects itself.  I'm thinking that having my users run hierarchy viewer is probably unacceptable, though.

EDIT:  The middle layout is actually a RelativeLayout containing the ListView, which might matter, I'm going to try and eliminate it.  I've posted a simplified version of my XML that gives an idea of what I'm looking at.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/top_table"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:stretchColumns="2"
        android:shrinkColumns="1">
        <!-- removed for simplicity -->
    </TableLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/title_table"
        android:layout_above="@id/ad_toolbar">
        <!-- removed for simplicity -->
        <ListView 
            android:id="@+id/android:list"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <!-- removed for simplicity -->
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you post the .xml of the layout?

Comment: The actual XML is pretty complicated, since the layout is composed of a few layout files that are used by different activities, but I've posted a simplified version above.  And I realized that the middle region is actually a RelativeLayout that contains the ListView, which might make a difference, I'm going to try and eliminate it.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason you're using RelativeLayout for the parent? This sounds like a case in which you should use a vertical LinearLayout containing the TableLayout, the ListView, and then the LinearLayout (in that order), where the ListView has layout_height="0dip" and layout_weight="1". When you set visibility on the bottom LinearLayout, the layout weight of the ListView should cause it to expand to fill the space.

Comment: layout_weight is the right solution. either he didn't think of that yet, or the problem is more complicated than we think? i doubt it though. that is why the xml would be useful. than we could just quickly fix it :D

Comment: It's a RelativeLayout because the layout file containing the top and bottom elements is used across several activities, and some of them use the fact that it's a RelativeLayout to position sub-elements appropriately.  Not all of the possible layouts work easily as a LinearLayout.